# XML data extract

Tags: sql, xml

I have SQL database table name `sales` in one of the column called, `msg`, we store XML files now I want to retrieve data from those XML files.
E.g
In XML I have fields named `sales person name`, `sales date`, `product code`.

There are 100 of product codes

I want to retrieve data with person name called **`Jacob`** and his sales done from **`01 August 2016`** for product code **`zer1200`** and **`ray4000`**.

Could you please advise me, how do I go about this?

Comment: Which database are you using? And is the column type xml ?

Comment: Tell the database you are using, Show some sample xml, show how it should be transformed to expected result.

Comment: I am suign SQL DB, yes the column type is XML...Sorry I cant post XML example here ..but consider it as normal XML

Comment: *I am suign SQL DB* is no new information. You have put this in the question already. Is it MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle or another? Please state vendor (**and version**). And please give a reduced sample of your XML. No one can help you to query XML without having see it. **There is no *normal XML*!**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the *msg* field needs to be defined as an XML field.

**'[sales person name][1]'** = first instance of sales person name in the XML

**varchar(20)** = export the value to a varchar field

```
select 
  msg('[sales person name][1]','varchar(20)')
from
sales
```